# How I can create an EPG for tv?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, television, epg

I'm new in this forum, and I've been working in my company as a front-end developer for 6 months, this is my first experience.
I'm working on a tv app.
I never created an epg and I really don't know what i have to do and the worst things is that on the tv not all the code works.
I just created the style [what I have done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Newx.png).
I hope that this is a good place to ask :)
thank you very much!
[Example of what I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSUZz.png)

Comment: I'm actually wondering the same. Did you ever find any good tutorials on programming (coding) and EPG?

Answer (score -1):

This is a *very general* question. Probably beyond the scope of stackoverflow. And yes, there are probably better places to ask.

Anyway. As it's your first question: *Welcome* to the community and here's my similarly general answer:

What you're trying to achieve is what *I* call (it's not a technical term) an "US-style TV listing", where data is organized in a mostly horizontal grid-layout, by air time. Made popular, I think, by US print magazines like *TV Guide*. An online version can be admired on [TV.com's listings](http://www.tv.com/listings/), for example

The "European TV listings"-layout (again, no official term) is mostly vertical, organized in per-station columns, with time vertical. Examples online are this [TV search service's EPG](https://mediatheksuche.de/epg) I've found or this similar looking online-version of a [German TV guide](https://www.tvspielfilm.de/tv-programm/tv-sender/) print magazine.

You're mentioning that you are developing for a TV, a *smart TV* I guess. That's also very general. Depending on your targeted platform, you'd have to look into device specific SDKs or a cross-device framework. many rely on rich HTML or similar underpinnings.

Not knowing your exact tech, there're so many possibilities, it's hard to give a helpful answer. Try looking into "data table" frameworks for your platform, or if there's anything usable for your purpose. Some come with elaborate JS helper code, or a widgets library.

In general, you'd need to wrangle some source of rich *TV airings metadata* into a tabular or grid layout. I don't know about the *sources* of such data or *licensing* issues entailed, but *make sure* (!) you respect other online EPG's [copyrights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intellectual_property). You'd have to go to the original data originators, probably, or license pre-processed data somewhere.

I'm stressing that as I'm already seeing you are using *official* station logo graphics - which worries me! These images are copyrighted and you'd need the owners' OK to use them, *especially* if your work is for profit. You're at a company, right? Then you *better raise* these *issues* in an in-depth conversation with your supervisor.

With all that said, it's probably a [too general](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) question. Go back and separate your problem into manageable chunks. Try to work on these and if there are more specific challenges that pop up, you're welcome to ask again.